# Search Revision History in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

Changes are automatically saved in a Google Docs.

However, a typical search across Google Docs does not include the revisions.

Similarly, these forum discussions sought an answer to the same problem: [How do I search my revision history?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/grb9QE0Himk)  and 
[How do I search my document's revision history?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/grb9QE0Himk) , and found a search is not possible.

Nevertheless, the discussions date back approximately a decade; therefore, I wonder if such search is now possible?